# Ruby gsub to validate and remove comma from the paid field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have got a form which accepts a “paid” field and I am attempting to
validate it.

It’s a numeric field but I want the user to be able to enter the paid amount without comma raising error by checking validation.

amol.rb

```
class Amol < ApplicationRecord

 validate :check_paid

 def check_paid 
   errors.add(:paid, '- Commas are not allowed') if paid.to_s.gsub(/,/,"").to_i
 end 

end
```

When I enter the paid amount as 12,535 then it raises the error displaying as below ;

```
1 error prohibited this article from being saved: Paid - Commas are not allowed
```

and that is okay.

But the problem is even if I remove comma from the input, still the error persists and I cannot create or update the form.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the desired result by using the validation as below;

validates :paid, numericality: { only_integer: true }, allow_nil: true

Now when I enter comma in the text field, I get the error displaying ;

```
Paid is not a number
```

On the other hand, If entered the number without comma and saves to the database as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you code above is:

```
if paid.to_s.gsub(/,/,"").to_i
```

This expression always return **true**. other simple way to check if **,** exists

```
errors.add(:paid, '- Commas are not allowed') if paid.to_s.include?(',')
```

But bare in mind that this does not mean your **paid** input is a valid number. You might need to add other validation like [empty](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) and [numeric number](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) .

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it didn't raise the error and 12,235 was saved as 12 .00 in the database.

Comment: In your case what is this value 12,235? Is it a 12235 or 12.235 and what you expect it to be saved? You should have mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks. It is Twelve thousand two hundred and thirty five but in my database it is been saved as only twelve ignoring all the values after the comma.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen are you sure you use this condition if paid.to_s.include?(','). with this the validation will fail and data will not be saved.

Comment: Yes I used the same and the validation failed .

Comment: Most probably I will share it later as I am away from the system. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195752/discussion-between-muhammad-yaseen-and-channa-ly).